# Save user states between menu interactions in Telegram bot

Tags: go, telegram-bot

I'm creating a trade Telegram bot and I suppose to have about 5 different menus (keyboards) to communicate with the user. On the first step I provide to user an ability to choose the exnchange to trade, after that she should choose the currency, then choose the price, then she could see another user orders etc.

From the backend view the user messages is just a text and I choose where to route the request by just analyzing that text (old school **switch** statement). For the first step is okay, I have only couple of exchanges so I know the user is on the first step, but when she chose the currency how could I know which exchange he had been chosen on the previous step? Of course I could use the database to save all user menus interactions, but I'm interested is there another choise exist?

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [InlineQuery](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinequery). You can store some key parameters through the dialog with user. For example, you can store them in `callback_data` field, if you are using `InlineKeyboard`.